# How to Change maxPasswdAge parameter in OpenLDAP in Linux

Tags: linux, openldap

I am trying to find how to change  some password policy settings in openLDAP (on a system-wide level -  not on a per user level) such that ALL LDAP account users (ie existing and new users) have their passwords set to expire after 90 days.

I know the main parameter that controls this is the **maxPasswdAge** parameter but I am not sure how to set this.

We are running openldap 2.3.43 on RHel 5.3.

Can anyone share their experience on this?